# Can't Update Ubuntu20.04 LTS

Tags: updates

When I run
sudo apt update
I get the following error:

```
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease               
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease             
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                       
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                 
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-proposed InRelease                 
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kivy-team/kivy-daily/ubuntu focal InRelease         
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kivy-team/kivy/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How to fix this and update !!!

Comment: no it did not solve my issue

Comment: Since April 2019, WebUpd8team doesn't offer Java packages. Where did you find instructions/suggestions to add that PPA? Anyway, you must remove that PPA. Simply run `sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:webupd8team/java`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/q/307/)

Comment: @Kulfy Thank you!!!
It solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Java (JDK) 8 Installer PPA by Webupd8 team is discontinued.

[https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)

You have to remove this ppa.

In order to install Java (15), see :

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/09/how-to-install-oracle-java-15-on-ubuntu.html